# Custom BOOL getter/setter in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, boolean, setter, getter

In my iPhone app I have a BOOL named `isAddressCell`. This works fine, and I can call this without an issue:

```
[cell setIsAddressCell:YES];
```

However, I have looked around at creating a custom setter method and had no luck creating one and it appears my BOOL is never actually set. I have below the setter method code I have tried which fails.

All I want to do it when `setIsAddressCell` is called, depending on the value, certain other actions will occur.

Current, non-functional setter method:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, setter = setIsAddressCell:) BOOL isAddressCell;

-(void)setIsAddressCell:(BOOL)addressCell
{
    if (addressCell)
    {
        //Do stuff...
    }
    else
    {
        //Do different stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `setter = setIsAddressCell:` is redundant (since the auto-generated setter is also `setIsAddressCell:`)

Comment: So, if I don't want to change the method name, then I can add my method without having to to add the setter to the property?

Comment: Yes you just override the default method like any other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was being a dummy. Tell if I am still doing it wrong, but I should have it like this:

```
-(void)setIsAddressCell:(BOOL)addressCell
{
    if (addressCell)
    {
        //Do stuff...
    }
    else
    {
        //Do different stuff...
    }

    isAddressCell = addressCell;
}
```

**isAddressCell = addressCell;**

That bit is the key, I stupidly didn't set the value at the end of my manual setter method. Doh.

Comment: Yes of course. I was abut to ask what exactly you do in "//Do stuff..." and "//Do different stuff..." and how you aim to actually set the property in your setter method. In the end setting the properties value is what a setter is all about. :)